# Transform in uppercase code inside angular ui-src

Tags: css, angularjs, routes, uppercase

I have this row inside an html file. Here is used angular and all I want to do is to transform in uppercase the "user_username". So when is outputed in the screen user_username I want it in uppercase.

```html
<a ui-sref="home.user({userId:user.user_username})">{{user.user_username}}</a>
```

I know how to transform in uppercase in css but don't have many knoledges in angular. Is there a way to transform  in uppercase this variable which is generated dinamically?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use angular filter [uppercase](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/uppercase). It should look something like this:

```
 {{ user.user_username | uppercase }}
```